# Publish one message without while infinite loop

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am using ROS Noetic. I tried to publish one message without "while infinite loop" in the node that I created.
In fact, I need just to publish one message from the topic to socketCAN but it doesn't work. I know that the node will be killed but it should publish one message?!! Anybody know why ?
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367450/publish-one-message-without-while-infinite-loop/) by [mros](https://answers.ros.org/users/58785/mros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-12-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) on 2020-12-10**:
We don't know what your code looks like and what message you are trying to publish and where. Please post your code, at least a snippet, so we can get context. Also, please be more detailed in your question. What have you tried so far and what errors you are facing (if any)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It most likely is the case that your publisher is publishing your message before any subscribers to that message have been connected. It takes a "non-zero" amount of time for the "hand-shaking" to occur through the ROS master and between the publisher/subscriber nodes. You can write a section of code that will wait for a subscriber, publish the message (to that subscriber) then shut down the node. If you immediately shutdown a node after calling publish on a publisher it is **not** guaranteed that the message was sent and received by the subscriber.

A convenient overload to the `advertise` function provided by the `NodeHandle` class allows a client to specify a `SubscriberStatusCallback` function pointer that gets called when a new subscriber connects to the publisher see the [rosdocs](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#ae4711ef282892176ba145d02f8f45f8d).

Here is a simple code example with a `std_msgs/String` topic:

```
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

#include <ros/ros.h>

void subscriberConnectCallback(const ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher& publisher)
{
  ROS_INFO("Super cool I got a new subscriber [%s] on the %s topic!", publisher.getSubscriberName().c_str(),
           publisher.getTopic().c_str());

  // Build the message and publish
  std_msgs::String msg;
  msg.data = "super cool";
  publisher.publish(msg);

  // Signal shutdown
  ros::shutdown();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "test_node");

  // Create publisher with private node handle and bind callback to handle subscriber connection
  ros::NodeHandle pnh("~");
  ros::Publisher publisher =
      pnh.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1, (ros::SubscriberStatusCallback)subscriberConnectCallback);

  // Spin this node until a shutdown is triggered
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [danambrosio](https://answers.ros.org/users/64471/danambrosio/) with karma: 106 on 2020-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mros](https://answers.ros.org/users/58785/mros/) on 2020-12-11**:
Hello, Thank you so much for your help, it works well but I had to remove  ("~").

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-12-11**:
@mros If this is the correct answer and it solved your issue, please mark this answer as correct.

**Comment by [danambrosio](https://answers.ros.org/users/64471/danambrosio/) on 2020-12-11**:
Just for your information, the private node handle is commonly used for publishers and would require a `rosrun` [argument remap](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments) or [launch remap](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap).

The ability to remap topics/services/actions is useful to prevent hardcoded topics/service names in a node.